# How to go to the BIOS setting of Packard Bell ENME69BMP laptop?

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I want to setup windows 7/8 in my Packard Bell ENME69BMP laptop newly by an USB  pendrive. It is currently  running on windows 8 .

But can't go the BIOS setting to make the pen-drive bootable . I have tried with the key : F1,F2,F9,F12,ESC,DEL when rebooting the PC but failed to go to the BIOS setting. Help please

Answer (score 1):

This thread implies that holding the shift key during boot will present you with USB boot options:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2189855

Comment: I put the information in my post, then linked for reference.

Comment: Why offer what might work instead of what will work?  In other words just explain how to do this through [`Advanced Startup Options`](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode)

Comment: That would make sense if he was asking about how to get into Safe mode, but that is not OPs question.  Are you just here to be a pain?  I provided information that will likely lead OP to the solution they are looking for, whats the problem?

Comment: **I don't feel you quoted all the relevant information from your link.**  My suggestion would also let him access to UEFI settings he wants to access guaranteed.

Comment: @Ramhound - please just post your solution as an additional answer.  Then both solutions can stand on their own merits.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://packard-bell-scandic.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6814/~/enabling-the-boot-device-menu, F12 can generally be used to access the boot menu.
If it's not enabled, F2 can be used to access the BIOS to enable it.

I have just tried both of these keys (basically just mashed them when the Packard Bell logo appeared), and it worked.

Another thought: you may need to hold down the <kbd>(Fn)</kbd> key as well to enable the F-key behaviour (e.g. <kbd>(Fn)+F2</kbd>).  The Function Key Behavior is also configurable in the setup utility.

Comment: For what it's worth: My ME69BMP laptop says it uses the "InsydeH20 Setup Utility", Rev 5.0.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to press Fn to enable F2 :-).  Bad enough that this "you need push Fn to enable F1 to F12" was introduced. But that manufacturers activate it already during boot ... . Why?